# In jmeter- for web service, how to provide load dynamically

Tags: jmeter

I want to provide load (i.e for 100 users there will be different data for all 100 users)to one of my webservice method dynamically using jmeter.

I have tried using _StringFromFile function but it is not feasible for me to create 100 csv file with different data for 100 users.

Want to know other functions of jmeter which can be use for creating load dynamically.

Looking forward for your reply....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following test elements for parametrization:

1. [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) - to get values from database
2. [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) - to get values from CSV file(s)
3. [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) - basically the same as point 2, might be more convenient and easy to use
4. [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - to provide random value

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using _StringFromFile function. _CSVRead() was not working for me.